# Is it possible to have 2 iCloud email accounts in IOS 5?

Tags: icloud

Under a Mobile Me Family Pack, I set up a secondary email account for myself, giving me two "username@me.com" addresses. When I transitioned to iCloud, I used my primary Mobile Me account, which I set up on my Mac and iPad. In June of 2012, Mobile Me will cease to exist, but I still need to use that second account. Is it possible to have both my primary iCloud email, and that secondary account on my iPad? (On my Mac, i just set up another User Account, and used it to "migrate" that second Mobile Me account to iCloud.)
I would Only need to sync Mail to my iPad for the latter, so would not be concerned with duplicating Adress Book contacts, Calendar etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you've already discovered that you can [migrate](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2706?viewlocale=en_US) each [MobileMe Family Member](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH1150) sub-account individually to iCloud. Having done that, you can now add the second account to your iPad as a secondary iCloud account by going to `Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Add Account… > iCloud`.

You can also add secondary iCloud accounts in OS X by going to `System Preferences > Mail, Contacts & Calendars > Add Account… > iCloud`. This way you don't have to switch users in OS X to access the second iCloud account's mail.

You can migrate remaining MobileMe Family Members by going to [me.com/move](http://www.me.com/move), instead of having to create a new user in OS X to do the migration.

Primary iCloud accounts can use a few features that secondary accounts can't:

- iOS 5: Photo Stream, Documents & Data, and Backup
- OS X Lion: Bookmarks, Photo Stream, Find My Mac, and iCloud Storage

Answer (score 1):

iCloud has a feature called "iCloud mail aliases" which allows users to create up to three so-called alias emails. Each of these is a completely separate email address which forwards email to you and lets you send email from it. Unfortunately, there's no way to have two separate *accounts* in iCloud, but this may prove useful to you anyway.

To set up a new alias, go to https://www.icloud.com/#mail and open Preferences, accessed via the gear icon in the top right. Under the Accounts tab, click "Add an alias…" and fill out the desired settings.

[image: Accounts pane]
The Accounts pane in iCloud Mail

[image: Mail alias creation]
Creating an alias

Comment: You are correct about aliases but it *is* possible to have multiple iCloud accounts and you can access the mail for those multiple accounts on a single iOS device or computer–which is what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @jaberg Oh, I hadn't thought it was... thanks for the clarification.